# Angular Placeholder options?

Tags: angular, angular-material, placeholder

Is there a way in Angular to configure placeholders to avoid the placeholder text above the input when input is selected or when input is not empty? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Can we have the code of this input ?

Comment: Sure, you have this code at https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview first example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the material solution :

```
export class className {
  options: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.options = fb.group({
      floatLabel: 'never',
    });
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dlbqojxyjyo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-label-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

User `floatLabel: 'never'` to avoid placeholder

```
constructor(_fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.userForm = this._fb.group({
      floatLabel: 'never',
    });
  }
```